# Dramatic Slowdown After 19.04 Update

Tags: 19.04

I updated my Ubuntu to 19.04 about a week ago. Previously, with each Ubuntu upgrade (I started at 17.11) I had experienced a boost in performance. However, since updating ot 19.04 somehow everything has become dramatically slower. After 5-6 hours working at the computer, everything slows down to a crawl and I have to restart.

The most noticeable of all this is when I try to interact with files. For example:

- After system boot, I cannot open "Files" (the application, Nautilus) for five to ten minutes. I click on the icon, and nothing happens.
- Whenever I do open Files, the application freezes for one to three seconds whenever I enter a new folder, try to delete, copy/past, see properties, or really any interaction with any file.
- When I try to move or delete something to or from the Desktop, again, the whole thing freezes, then the Desktop sort of "restarts itself" -- the screen "blinks": all icons disappear, and then reappear after 1-2 seconds.

These are the most obvious examples, but things like these are happening all over. Any clue of what might be causing this, or especially how I can fix it?

Thank you kindly

Comment: In a terminal, start `top` or `htop`, open Nautilus and see what comes up on the top of the list.

Comment: Thank you! I have done this and tried to copy/paste a file, and I see that the gnome shell is taking basically 100% of the CPU. Any idea of why?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 comes with Gnome Shell 3.32 which has a much better performance than previously... Are you actually running 3.32? Enter `gnome-shell --version` in a terminal.

Comment: Some malfunctioning GNOME extension(s) may be the reason.

Comment: Hi, I just checked, and yes, I am running 3.32... how about the malfunctioning Gnome extensions? How would I find that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pomsky suggested, the issue was with the GNOME extensions. In this case, Desktop icons. Once I remove it, all was fine.

Thank you! :)