# Ubuntu 19.04 running so slow; crashing with minimal programs running

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04

My computer is running sooo slow.

It has a heap of loop file systems, which seems excessive although I'm really unsure of what to do, but it crashes sometimes when I'm just watching YouTube, with nothing else open, so understandable I hope to fix this issue. 
It's also maxed out on swap memory.

I'm not great with terminology, but I am happy to provide any additional info if needed.
I'm running Ubuntu 19.04.

Any help will be hugely appreciated :)

```
  PID  USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                           
 4043 sayne     20   0 3792640 186512  49396 R 100.0   4.8   6:37.29 gnome-shell                                                 
 2993 root      20   0  300548  69696  58704 R  50.0   1.8  13:58.37 Xorg                                                                  
32412 sayne     20   0   12048   3632   2688 R  50.0   0.1   0:07.84 top                                                                               
    1 root      20   0  168152   5604   2740 S   0.0   0.1   0:10.82 systemd                                                                           
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd                                                                          
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                            
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
```

Comment: You can try running `top` in a terminal to see what is going on. Also, have a look at this, maybe your issue is similar: https://askubuntu.com/q/1143924/874649

Comment: Thankyou, though I'm sort of unsure what I'm looking at here :(

Comment: The `top` command shows a list of processes, by default sorted so that the most CPU-consuming processes are at the top of the list. Which processes do you see there when you run `top` and what is shown in the "%CPU" column?

Comment: Please edit your original question to add information about what `top` shows, then it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: apologies, I'm new to all this, bad formatting :/

Comment: OK, so we can see that it is the `gnome-shell` process that is causing trouble, since it uses 100% CPU.

Comment: True, I figured as much :)
So what steps can I take to rectify this, genuinly appreciative of your help Elias :)

Comment: I don't know exactly how to fix it but it seems similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1036441/874649   Maybe it is something that has been fixed, in that case updating your system could help. Run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` -- does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( Looking over the other post, but no such luck as yet to fixing problem, will keep searching, any other ideas appreciathed though :)

Comment: I suppose you already tried rebooting after updating?

Comment: Yeah, have tried that, to no avail.

Comment: Another thing worth trying: disable all gnome extensions, as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029385/874649

Comment: Though I don't think it has completly fixed problems, is definatley running a lot better, thankyou :)

Comment: Great! To help others, you can write what you did as an answer, under "Your Answer" below. (it is fine to answer your own question.) Then it will be easier for others having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Though computer is still running far too slow, this certainly did help speed it up somewhat:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions true`

Comment: If you run `top` again after that, does it still show `gnome-shell` using 100% CPU?

Comment: Not %100 anymore, so that's a plus :) 66.7%

Comment: OK so then it is probably still `gnome-shell` that is making your system slow. It should not use any noticeable resources, I think it is normally below 1% CPU usage. So most probably something is still wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking you're right. I read something on the post u posted a link to, about maybe needing to wait til the update is released, so will keep looking around, or hopefully having it fixed when that happens. Running at below 15% would be brilliant :)